# Simplifying huge expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify a huge expression. There are many terms like in form as below in my huge expression.

```
(-(((-8 g h (g + h) (2 g + h) + 
           6 a (2 g^3 + 3 g^2 h + g h^2 + h^3)) Cos[t]^2)/(
        48 a eta h (g + h) \[Pi])) - ((-8 g h (g + h) (g + 2 h) + 
          6 a (g^3 + g^2 h + 3 g h^2 + 2 h^3)) Cos[t]^2)/(
       48 a eta g (g + h) \[Pi]))
```

The problem is that, when I want to simplify my huge expression, MM can not do that after 10 hours. Is there any sterategy which can help me? I have uploaded my code [here](https://files.fm/u/fw8qdbcc).

Comment: Pattern matching involved in simplification almost certainly involves much larger time complexity on input size than linear O(n). One approach to attack the problem could be simplifying the expression in piecewise manner, for instance if it's a large sum, each summand at a time, and then possibly reapplying simplification to the piecewise simplified expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. The problem is, I can not separate exp to piecewise parts. Please take a look at my code in the link. @kirma

Comment: I have added the link to the question. @kirma

Comment: I don't think I have time to dwell deeper on this at least for now (I'm at work after all), but having concrete material you supplied to work on definitely helps!

Comment: If the expression is huge, Mma anyway needs time to cope with it, and the time may be considerable, since Mma must try out a huge number of possibilities to find a best among them. There can be a problem that the best possibility is defined by the minimal value of complexity, and the huge expression has a potential to have a number of forms with the same minimal complexity. I am not aware of the way MMa operates in such a case, but expect that this may be a reason of slowing down. A good idea would be to help Mma. If you know something simplifying about the expression

Comment: (Continuation)  (at least on the initial stage).  For example, in the expression you gave above the terms are proportional to `Cos[t]^2`. May be, you can separate out other factors like this and then `Select` the terms with common factors and simplify them separately, and later unify them together. Another, mechanical way would be to turn this into a list  `List @@ expr` where `expr` is your complete expression, then separate the list into a nested list containing only several terms each using `Partition`

Comment: (Continuation)  and then `Simplify` separately each sublist, and later combine them back and simplify again. I guess though that such a mechanical way does not have many chances to bring a good result.

Comment: Do you have good reason to expect a much more simplified form? If your expression is so huge that MMA takes +10 hours, then maybe the simplified form is not so simple either. What then? What will you use it for? If we know that, then maybe we can find an alternative approach together :)

Comment: I want to simplify it and then use series to expand it @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: What constitutes "huge"?  What is its `LeafCount`?  Also, I presume that you are building this huge expression from smaller pieces.  If so, use `Simplify` as you construct your expression.  Also, using `Collect` in conjunction with `Simplify` sometimes is helpful.  Finally, be sure to use `Simplify`, not `FullSimplify`, on polynomial expressions.  The latter can be much slower.